# Efficiently pipe in-memory file contents to a command line command

Tags: ruby, linux, command-line

I have a ruby script that, at one point, has an in-memory file that may or may not be backed by an entry in the filesystem. The naive solution would be to create a tempfile if a filesystem entry does not exist, but this will result in the command line command re-reading the file into memory.

Ideally, I would like to avoid reading the file into memory more than once since it could potentially be quite large.

Now, the command line command does accept a piped input, so I thought this might be a good solution, but I cannot find any way to achieve piping a Ruby File object's contents into something happening on the command line.

I'm also open to other recommendations if I'm coming at this from the wrong direction. The files not backed by a filesystem entry are being read from a remote HTTP stream.

Comment: Rather than describing what you think should be the solution, it would be more productive to tell what are you trying to do? Why do you want to pipe in-memory file contents to command line?

Comment: @LieRyan That is why the last paragraph was written... I'm happy to elaborate if needed, but I thought it pretty well described the situation.

Comment: What do you mean by an “in memory file”? Do you have file contents in a string that you want to use?

Comment: @matt I mean a Ruby File object, which may be created using [OpenURI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) or by opening a true file from the file system. I have also considered removing the OpenURI wrapper and just using a raw HTTP request to retrieve the data since OpenURI uses a Tempfile object under the hood.

Comment: @Dan: yes, the last paragraph means you're open to other suggestions,  but how are we supposed to give you suggestions if we don't know what you're trying to do? Why do you think you want what you want to do? How did you end up in the situation that you now think can be solved by yourproposed solution? As of now, IMO the question is too vague to be answerable.

Comment: @LieRyan, I respectfully disagree. You know that I have a situation where I either have a local or remote path to a file, you know processing is happening in Ruby, and you know that I have processing of those same files that needs to happen through external programs that cannot be accessed within the Ruby process. As I said before, I'm happy to elaborate, but I am not sure what more information you are wanting.

Comment: For starter you can elaborate how the Ruby program are started and how the other program are started. Do you start both programs from the shell? Or does the Ruby Program starts the other programs? Do you write the other program? What library are you getting your in-memory file from? Are you serving a web file upload or are you loading a URL? Don't make us guess.

Comment: Sure. I'm happy to answer those specific questions. The Ruby program is running as part of a web service in the Rails framework. The file manipulation will be happening on a background thread following the service being provided with either the file itself or a URL pointing to the file to be processed. The ruby program starts the various external programs depending on the type of file. These other programs are not developed by me. Again, if you need additional clarification I'm happy to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to read the `IO`s contents into a string, and then use something like [`Kernel#open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-open) (with a `|`), [`IO::popen`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-popen) or [`open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) to create the subprocess and write the contents to the subprocesses stdin:

```
f = the_file_or_io_object
data = f.read

IO::popen('the_command', 'r+') do |io|
  io.write data
  io.close_write
  puts io.read
end
```

Although this avoids going writing the file to disk (unless it already is with e.g. a tempfile) it involves reading the file contents into memory and then passing them to the subprocess, so they are in memory twice. If you want to avoid that you could use [`fork`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-fork) (if your system has it) and [`reopen`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-reopen):

```
# f as before, no need to read it in this time

pid = fork do
  $stdin.reopen f
  # Now stdin is the file, so when the command is run it will see 
  # it on its stdin
  exec 'the_command'
end

Process.wait pid
```

If you’re on Windows you probably won’t have `fork`, so you could try [`spawn`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn), redirecting `stdin`:

```
pid = spawn 'the_command', :in => f

Process.wait pid
```

Comment: Thanks! The reopen method looks like the ticket.  I'll hold off on accepting to give others a chance to answer, but I'll probably go with this.